# custom query - offset to pagination

Tags: wp-query, loop, pagination

I'm trying ot add a custom query to my pagination - category page.

here is the code how it look like:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template used for displaying Blog loop
 *
 * Use for index/archive/search.
 * 
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage UnicMag
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

/**
 * Must print title before query_posts
 */
punica_page_title();

$is_page_template = is_page_template( 'templates/blog-1.php' );

if ( $is_page_template ) {
    // make custom blog query if is blog page template
    query_posts( 'post_type=post&paged=' . get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
}
?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) { ?>
```

I tried to change the query like:

```
query_posts( 'post_type=post&paged=' . get_query_var( 'offset=3' ) );
```

or

```
    query_posts('offset=3');
```

but no luck for me :/

Starting to hit a wall with my head. . .

if anybody can highlite me before to break it, it will be super nice :)

Thank you guys !

--- edit --

```
<?php
/**
 * The template used for displaying Blog loop
 *
 * Use for index/archive/search.
 * 
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage UnicMag
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

/**
 * Must print title before query_posts
 */
punica_page_title();

$is_page_template = is_page_template( 'templates/blog-1.php' );

if ( $is_page_template ) {
    // make custom blog query if is blog page template
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
query_posts( 'offset=3&post_type=post&paged=' . $paged ); }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried something like  `query_posts( 'post_type=post&offset=3&showposts=2' ) );`, as example?

Comment: yes .  . and no sucess :(

Comment: Never ever use query_posts, it breaks the main query and page functionality. As this is the index page, use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query accordingly